# Issue Django V 1.11.16 Admin Search Not Working with all Data

Tags: mysql, django, search

I developed an application form in Django I added 500 +- records using the Django admin, then I imported 9000 records using MySql. In the Django admin I can see all records perfectly. However, when I search for xxx record does not find it but I can see the record on the admin right there. It is weird because when I search the records I added using the Django admin the search works and display them correctly. If I want to search for a record or records that was imported using MySql import (9000 records) does not find them. If I filter them, yes I see the records, if I type the same search for the filter does not show them. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a MILLON.

This is for a Linux server running on AWS, running MySQL, Python, Django 1.11.16 I changed the filters, add filters, checked the search_fields, restart the server.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import ApplicationForm, Supervisor
from .forms import AdminForm
from advanced_filters.admin import AdminAdvancedFiltersMixin
from apps.users import views
# Register your models here.


class ReadOnly(AdminAdvancedFiltersMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = []
    advanced_filter_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phoneNumber', 'city', 'state', 'socialSecurityNumber', 'other city', 'project', 'agreement_signed_date', 'middle_name', 'supervisor__name', 'gender', 'Marital_status', 'home_address1', 'home_address2', 'postCode', 'dateOFBirth', 'no_of_dependents', 'emergency_contact_firstName', 'emergency_contact_lastName', 'emergency_contact_phoneNumber', 'emergency_contact_relation', 'ceiling_mechanic', 'framing_mechanic', 'drywall_hanger', 'drywall_finisher', 'general_larborer', 'painter_tradesman', 'plaster_tradesman', 'layout_blueprint', 'drywall_wood_framing', 'drywall_painter', 'cabinets', 'safety_jobsite', 'masonry_bricklayer', 'masonry_blocklayer', 'carpenter', 'concrete_forming', 'concrete_finisher', 'osha_manager', 'project_manager', 'is_osha10', 'is_osha30', 'is_osha_training_manager', 'work_eligible_military')

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        group = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
        if len(group) == 0:
            return list(self.readonly_fields) + ['id_identifier']
        else:
            if group[0] == 'View Users':
                return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
                       [field.name for field in obj._meta.fields] + \
                       [field.name for field in obj._meta.many_to_many]

        return self.readonly_fields

class ApplicationAdmin(ReadOnly):
    form = AdminForm

    list_display = ['id_identifier', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phoneNumber','agreement_signed_date', 'city',
                    'reg_form_thumb', 'i9_form_thumb', 'w4_form_thumb']
    list_filter = ['state', 'city', 'postCode']
    search_fields = ['postCode', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'city', 'phoneNumber', 'project', 'phoneNumber', 'supervisor__name']
    readonly_fields = ['id_identifier','created_date', 'last_update', 'reviewed_date']
```

I should see all data from the admin when I search but does not display all data.
Please take a look a the images and you will see the issue, if I search for ALTON it shows zero records, when I filter for ALTON it shows 5 results. Pretty weird.

[Filtering data and display all forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1XnP.png)

[Searching the data and does not display anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oApdk.png)

Comment: I have the same issue with `Django==1.11.23`, I never had this issue before, the search functionality stopped working without reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! I have fixed the issue installing the django-haystack, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch modules. The search is working perfectly. Cheers!